# Object class toString() combined with Widening

Tags: java

My code is below, i have three output and in three toString() method of Object class is called which gives output in form of class@hashcodeinhexadecimal form then why in output 1 in which autoboxing and widening happens internally the value of object get print ?

```
public class AutoBoxingUn
{

    static Object pp= new Object ();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   


        int q = 10;
        Object o=q;
        System.out.println("O"+"..."+o.toString());     \\ O...10    ( output 1 )

        System.out.println(pp.toString());          \\ java.lang.Object@ee7d9f1 ( output 2 )

        A aa= new A(11);
        System.out.println(aa);                 \\ A@1edf1c96   ( output 3 )
    }



}

class A extends AutoBoxingUn
{   int o;
    A(int o)
    {
        this.o=o;
    }
    void m2()
    {}
}
```

Comment: `Integer` extends `Object` and *overrides* `Object`'s `toString()` method. Your class `A` does not override `toString()` with a custom implementation and hence only inherits the one implemented in `Object`.

Comment: Integer does overrides Object's toString() but i am printing o which is object of Object class so doesn't it has to class Object's toString().
If i hover over the toString() in eclipse IDE then it is calling String java.lang.Object.toString() method only

Comment: "printing o which is object of Object class" - No. `o` is *declared* as `Object`, but at *runtime* it holds an object of type `Integer` (which *is an* `Object` too). Hence, at runtime, the `toString()` of the actual object is called, which is an instance of `Integer`. Read up about inheritance, virtual methods and overriding in OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object o internally hold Integer value, therefore at runtime toString() method of Integer class is called which overrides Object class toString() method for printing the object / integer

Answer (score 1):

if you that toString() method of Objetc class should get called then change   Object o=q; to Object o = new Object(); in your code

Answer (score 0):

> why in output 1 in which autoboxing and widening happens internally the value of object get print ?

`o.toString()` calls the `toString` implementation of `Integer` class, since that's the runtime time of `o` (since you assigned an `int` to an `Object` reference, which caused an `Integer` object to be assigned to that variable).

Therefore 10 is printed.

Comment: but If i hover over the toString() in eclipse IDE then it is calling String java.lang.Object.toString() method only and not Integer class, please explain

Comment: @BharatData the IDE shows you the implementation that matches the compile time type of the variable on which you are calling the method (which is `Object` in this case). It doesn't (and in most case cannot) analyze your code in order to determine what the runtime type of that variable would be. Therefore it can't show you `Integer`'s `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand, try `instanceof` operator as bellow

```
int q = 10;
Object o=q;
    if(o instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println("o is an Integer");
    } else {
        System.out.println("o is an Object");
    }
```

O/P : 
***`o is an Integer`***

That means : o is a reference of Object and pointing to Integer object, so `o.toString()` will call `toString()` method of `Integer` class. The Integer class which internally extended Object class and override(and has own implementation) Object's toString() method.

Comment: For an example like this, you should `o.getClass` instead. Using `instanceof` works only if you know the class you are expecting

Comment: @AxelH, Yes we can do that if o is not null, else it will be NPE :)

Comment: But I will have a correct result ;) `null instanceof ...` is always false, `null` is not an instance of anything. So you have to check for `null` too if you want a correct result.